# Trouble swapping values as keys in generic java BST class

Tags: java, generics

I was given a generic binary search tree class with the following declaration:

```
public class BST<K extends Comparable<K>, V>
```

I was asked to write a method that reverses the BST such that the values become the keys and keys become values. When I call the following method (defined in the class given)

```
reverseDict.put(originalDict.get(key), key);
```

I get the following two error messages from Netbeans:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym  type: BST.put

And also:

> no suitable method found for `put(V,K)` method `BST.put(BST<K,V>.Node,K,V)` is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) method `BST.put(K,V)` is not applicable (actual argument `V` cannot be converted to `K` by method invocation conversion) where `V`,`K` are type-variables:
>
> `V extends Object` declared in method `<K,V>reverseBST(BST<K,V>)`
>
> `K extends Comparable<K>` declared in method `<K,V>reverseBST(BST<K,V>)`

From what the error messages are telling me, since my values do not extend `Comparable` I am unable to use them as keys. If I am right, how can I get around that without changing the class given (maybe a cast)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need a `V extends Comparable<V>` in order to use it as key, but you have only a `V` without bounds. I *think* you need to write a static method like..

```
public static <A extends Comparable<A>, B extends Comaparable<B>> 
    BST<B,A> invert(BST<A,B> bst) {...}
```

.. in order to ensure that additional condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `public class BST<K extends Comparable<K>, V>` must have `put` method (usually `insert` in tree) to avoid this error. Also `get` method too.

Add this method

```
public void put(K key, V value) {
   // add key and associated value to this BST; 
}
```

and call the method by

```
reverseDict.put(originalDict.get(key), key) ;
```

Here is an wonderful example for [Binary Search Trees](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~skrentny/cs367-common/readings/Binary-Search-Trees/index.html) that you can refer.

Comment: my class already has that method defined.Sorry if it wasn't clear. The problem is it fails when I call that method because V is not Comparable.